# Authentication methods allowed by default in OpenSSH on Alpine

Tags: security, openssh, docker

I'm experimenting with Docker's Alpine Linux image and OpenSSH.  The `sshd_config` file that ships with alpine has everything commented out by default.  I only uncomment `Port 22`.  I assume this is the most secure configuration (But would like some feedback on whether this assumption is correct).

I then run `ssh-keygen -q` to generate the user keys (For root) and `ssh-keygen -A` to generate the host keys.  I then `cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys` so that I can log in with the key.

When I log in from the host with `ssh localhost` I get prompted to accept the host key and then I get in.  So everything seems to be working fine.  However if I try to connect from outside the docker conatainter / host I get prompted for a password.  Should this happen?  My assumption was that since I only configured the `Port` parameter everything else would be turned off including password authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However if I try to connect from outside the docker conatainter / host I get prompted for a password. Should this happen? My assumption was that since I only configured the Port parameter everything else would be turned of including password authentication.

Yes. The password authentication is on by default, because it is sometimes the only method you can access newly installed servers. But you can simply turn it off using `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` and `PasswordAuthentication no` in your `sshd_config`.